# "Is not a function" error even though function shows up as a function in console

Tags: javascript

I have an object called *Utils.MediaQuery*. I am trying to access its *isMobile()* function.

However, for some reason, trying to access that function returns a "not a function" error. Worse (and difficult for debugging), the object shows up as having the function in Firefox console, ***and*** shows up as ***not*** having the function in Firefox console.

Debugging code:

```
console.log("Utils.MediaQuery:", Utils.MediaQuery);
console.log("Utils.MediaQuery.isMobile():", Utils.MediaQuery.isMobile());
```

Result:

[image: Console error illustration]

(The "Object" part in the bottom half is what I get when clicking on the Utils.MediaQuery object)

The logged Object doesn't have the isMobile() function, but its description does.

The guilty object:

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {

    Utils = {};

    Utils.MediaQuery = {
        SCREEN_WIDTH_SMALL: 568,
        SCREEN_WIDTH_MEDIUM: 720,
        SCREEN_WIDTH_LARGE: 1010,
        SCREEN_WIDTH_XLARGE: 1400  // in px
    };

    $(function(){
        Utils.$window = $(window);
        Utils.$html = $('html');
        Utils.$body = Utils.$html.find('body');

        Utils.MediaQuery.getViewportWidth = function() {
            return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth,
                window.innerWidth || 0);
        };

        Utils.MediaQuery.isMobile = function() {
            return (Utils.MediaQuery.getViewportWidth() < Utils.MediaQuery.SCREEN_WIDTH_MEDIUM);
        };
    });

});
```

**What can cause this kind of behavior?**

---

PS: This is from a big clunky legacy project I just joined. Considering I am still mostly unable to *understand* its architecture, I'm afraid
I can't explain it either

PPS: Seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762033/object-parameter-undefined-even-though-shows-in-console), which in turn links to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json), but in both cases I couldn't see how the answers applied to the current problem. Sorry if I was wrong.

Comment: I suspect it is a case of [deferred console evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection), yes. When you logged it, it didn't have that property. Later, when you expanded that entry in the console, it did, so it showed it to you.

Comment: Can you console log: `Utils.MediaQuery.isMobile` (without parentheses).

Comment: @praszyk This returned "undefined"

Comment: So, it's just you're trying to access the method too early. You should defile the method in the upper part, not inside the jQuery function executed on document ready.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Seems that's it yes, but considering all properties are added at the same time, what could cause this? I added a description of the object declaration, to try and make it clearer

Comment: @Cristol.GdM: They *aren't* added all at the same time. All of the ones inside the `$(function() { /*...*/});` aren't added until later, when jQuery fires its `ready` callbacks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ooooh ok, that makes sense. Guess that's the answer I needed. Thanks!